# How to further refactor a ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I'm writing a function that takes a string and returns a corresponding model class. The old version consists of ugly case statements, and the refactored version has a less-ugly hash. However the hash still feels repetitive to me. Could you give me some advice?

```
# original function

def determine_node_label(category)
  label = 
    case category 
    when 'boundary box'
      Slide
    when 'circle', 'rectangle'
      GroupBox
    when 'text'
      Text
    when 'picture', 'pie', 'bar' , 'trend', 'star'
      Content
    else
      Content
    end
  return label 
end

# refactored function

def determine_node_label(category)
  label = {
    "boundary box" => Slide,
    "circle" => GroupBox,
    "rectangle" => GroupBox,
    "text" => Text,
    "picture" => Content,
    "pie" => Content,
    "bar" => Content,
    "trend" => Content,
    "star" => Content
  }
  label.default = Content
  return label["category"]
end
```

update:

I would be more interested in solutions that assume that the `label.default` is subject to change. My apologies for not making this clear in the code.

Comment: Both methods work. And you didn't explain why you find one version _ugly_ and the one _less ugly_. What are you optimizing for? Shortness? Readability? Maintainability? Performance? Memory consumption?

Comment: I think the refactored version is more readable as `category` and `label` grow larger(in terms of lines taken).

Comment: Another option you might want to consider is an object-oriented design in which instead of using a simple string to name a `category` you could use value objects or different classes to represent a category. And the object could just know its category name and its label class.

Comment: The two methods are not equivalent. The second one always returns `Content` no matter what the input is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
LABELS = {
  "boundary box" => Slide,
  "circle"       => GroupBox,
  "rectangle"    => GroupBox,
  "text"         => Text
} 

def determine_node_label(category)
  LABELS[category] || Content
end
```

Comment: Hmm...this feels better. But just curious, what would I do if I change my `label.default` to, say, `Others` while keeping all the explicit `Content` key-value pairs?

Comment: Please do not change your question multiple times that makes it hard to keep up with changing the answer... If you want to return `Others` as a default or fallback then you certainly will need to be more explicit and will need to list all `Content` categories.

Comment: Sorry about the change in my hindsight. The edited question reveals the part that I can't figure out. Thanks for making everything clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you do want the dynamic default value, you can use [`Hash.fetch`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch). Also, pass the default value as the method parameter.

```
LABELS = {
  "boundary box" => Slide,
  "circle"       => GroupBox,
  "rectangle"    => GroupBox,
  "text"         => Text
} 

def determine_node_label(category, default = 'Content')
  LABELS.fetch(category, default)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For ease of maintainability I suggest the data be maintained in the following hash.

```
DATA = {
  %w| boundary\ box |              => 'Slide',
  %w| circle rectangle |           => 'GroupBox',
  %w| text |                       => 'Text',
  %w| picture pie bar trend star | => 'Content'
}
  #=> {["boundary box"]=>"Slide", ["circle", "rectangle"]=>"GroupBox",
  #    ["text"]=>"Text", ["picture", "pie", "bar", "trend", "star"]=>"Content"}
```

Note that I made the values literals (strings) to demonstrate how this hash will be manipulated. In the actual application the values would not necessarily be literals.

Then provide a method to create the desired hash `h` from `DATA` and a specified default value (the latter to be returned by `h[k]` when `h` does not have a key `k`).

```
def data_to_hash(data, default)
  data.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| k.each { |obj| h[obj] = v } }.
       tap { |h| h.default = default }
end
```

This might be used as follows.

```
h = data_to_hash(DATA, 'Cat')
  #=> {"boundary box"=>"Slide", "circle"=>"GroupBox",
  #    "rectangle"=>"GroupBox", "text"=>"Text", "picture"=>"Content",
  #    "pie"=>"Content", "bar"=>"Content", "trend"=>"Content",
  #    "star"=>"Content"}
h["boundary box"]
  #=> "Slide"
h["pie"]
  #=> "Content"
h["cake"]
  #=> "Cat"
```

To subsequently change the default you could either call `data_to_hash` again, with the revised default, or simply execute

```
h.default = "Dog"
```

or wrap the latter in a method.

```
def change_default(h, new_default)
  h.default = new_default
end

change_default(h, "Dog")
  #=> "Dog"
h["pie"]
  #=> "Content"
h["cake"]
  #=> "Dog"
```